# Expand $sin(z)$ about $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

It seems like all you have to do is use the fact that:

$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^n(z_o)}{n!}(z-z_o)^n$

In this scenario, $z_o=\pi$.

The solution I got is:

$\frac{sin(\pi)}{0!}(z-z_o)^0 + \frac{cos(\pi)}{1!}(z-z_o)^1 + \frac{-sin(\pi)}{2!}(z-z_o)^2 + \frac{-cos(\pi)}{3!}(z-z_o)^3 + \frac{sin(\pi)}{4!}(z-z_o)^4 + ...$

This simplifies to:

$(z-\pi) - \frac{(z-\pi)^3}{6} + \frac{(z-\pi)^5}{120} - ...$

I do not know if that is right, however.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see everything is fine here....

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi) = -1$ and not $1$.

Comment: Silly error on my end.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks right, you can check your answer with Wolfram Alpha:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+sin%28x%29+about+x%3Dpi

Comment: Thanks.  That is helpful, but there seems to be an issue with the signs.  Wolfram Alpha has it starting with a negative and then alternating positive and negative, whereas my solution begins with a positive and then alternates.  Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: It's right -- WA just changed the order of the terms inside the parentheses, and since all the powers are odd, it's equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

It might be of help if you proceed as follows: Note that
$$\sin(z) = \sin(z-\pi + \pi) = \sin(z-\pi) \cos(\pi) + \cos(z-\pi) \sin(\pi) = - \sin(z-\pi)$$
Setting $z-\pi = w$, we now have
$$\sin(z) = - \sin(w) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{w^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{(z-\pi)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$